# Permissions on Azure DevOps Artifacts and private npm repository

Tags: azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

We use a self-hosted Azure DevOps server for our private npm packages.
We've had success using Azure Pipelines to build and deploy packages to Azure Artifacts. This works fine but I and my colleagues can still publish from the npm command `npm publish`.

Can anyone tell me how to publish packages only from Azure pipelines and prevent users to publish from their development machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this official doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/feeds/feed-permissions?view=azure-devops#permissions-table

You need to set permission in this place:

[image]

[image]